# How to add SQLite (SQLite.NET) to my C# project

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2008, sqlite

I followed the instructions in the documentation:

> *Scenario 1:  Version Independent (does not use the Global Assembly Cache)*
>
> This method allows you to drop any new
>   version of the System.Data.SQLite.DLL
>   into your application's folder and use
>   it without any code modifications or
>   recompiling.  Add the following code
>   to your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

My app.config file now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="DataFeed.DataFeedSettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <DataFeed.DataFeedSettings>
            <setting name="eodData" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
        </DataFeed.DataFeedSettings>
    </userSettings>
    <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider" 
             invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" 
             type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

My project is called "DataFeed":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SQLite; //<-- Causes compiler error

namespace DataFeed
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> .\dev\DataFeed\Program.cs(5,19):
>   error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'SQLite' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

I'm prefer not to use the GAC so I simply dropped the `System.Data.SQLite.dll` into my `.\dev\DataFeed\` folder. I thought that all I needed to do is add the DLL to the project folder as it was mentioned in the documentation, but I can't use the library. Any hints on how to actually make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dropped the DLL into your `.\Dev\DataFeed` folder - and did you add a reference to that DLL to your project?? The error you get seems to indicate you don't have a reference set up to that DLL - this won't happen just by itself, you need to manually add a reference to an external DLL if you want to use stuff from it.

Comment: @Lirik: sometimes it's the simple stuff that gets in your way and you can't see it yourself :-) Been there, experienced that....

Comment: I guess it happens, especially at 1:00 in the morning :)... the brain starts thinking about sleeping and I'm still asking it to think about developing.